# Issues with conditionals in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm using Scheme with the full Swindle package, and I'm trying to use conditionals to recursively determine evenness/oddity of integers.  My code is as follows:

```
(define (odd? x)(
            (cond 
              ((= x 0) '#f)
              ((= x 1) '#t)
              ((= (even? (- x 1)) #t) '#f)
              (else '#t))))

(define (even? x)(
              (cond
                ((= x 0) '#f)
                ((= x 2) '#t)
                ((= (odd? (- x 1)) #t) '#f)
                (else '#t))))
```

However, when I run `(even? x)` or `(odd? x)` [`x` is some number, doesn't matter what, as I get the same error] I get:

```
 application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #t
  arguments...: [none]
```

Can anyone help?  I'm not 100% familiar with ideal Scheme syntax, so it might be that. Thanks.

Comment: First You have an extra parenthesis before your cond statements. Second '=' only does comparisons of numerical values. You already expect even? to return a true of false. 3. Why are you jumping between even and odd, the size or your stack keeps growing this way. just skip the third case and have your else jump to a tail call of (even? (- x 2)). 4. what about the negative numbers?

Comment: @WorBlux to your 3., in Scheme mutually tail-recursive procedures are guaranteed to run in constant stack space. The OP's code is naturally transformed into such a form. -- the point is in using Peano arithmetics.

Answer (score 0):

You have an erroneous pair of parentheses surrounding the `cond` expression (that's causing the error reported). But also, there are way too many conditions in each procedure, and because you're using `=` to compare numbers with boolean values, there will be a point where a contract violation will occur. For fixing that you can replace `=` with `equal?` in here:

```
((equal? (even? (- x 1)) #t) '#f)
```

And in here:

```
((equal? (odd? (- x 1)) #t) '#f)
```

But then, the procedures will still give an incorrect result:

```
(even? 5)
=> #t
(odd? 7)
=> #f
```

Honestly, I think it'd better to simplify the implementation, that will solve all the problems. Try this instead:

```
(define (odd? x)
  (cond ((= x 0) #f)
        (else (even? (- x 1)))))

(define (even? x)
  (cond ((= x 0) #t)
        (else (odd? (- x 1)))))
```

Now we'll get correct answers:

```
(even? 4)
=> #t
(even? 5)
=> #f
(odd? 6)
=> #f
(odd? 7)
=> #t
```

Comment: your 3rd objection is incorrect. OP's `even?`/`odd?` are only called with `x,x-1,0,2,1` and only return `#t,#f`.

Comment: @WillNess is not incorrect. Take OP's code, remove the extra `()` surrounding the `cond` and run `(even? 4)`. You'll get a `contract violation expected: number? given: #t` error.

Comment: a-ha! MIT Scheme is better (here)! ;) ;) it gives me *`";The object #t, passed as the first argument to integer-equal?, is not the correct type."`* i.e. it is an issue with using `=` to compare Boolean values: trying `(= #f #t)` gives me the same error. So it's `=` which receives a Boolean, not one of the functions. :)

Comment: @WillNess got your point. I edited my answer with your suggestions, thanks!

Comment: @WillNess But also notice: by simply replacing `=` with `equal?`, OP's code still fails: `(even? 5)` returns `#t`

Answer (score 0):

Any Scheme form in parentheses is an *application*, like `(sin 42)` or `(42 sin)`. The first calls `sin` as a function with argument `42` and produces a value; the second tries to call `42` with an argument `sin`, but `42` is no procedure, so this causes an error.

Similarly `(42)` is an application with no arguments; still it must have a procedure to be applied as its first part, to be called with no arguments, right?

In Scheme, *parentheses matter*, they are not just for grouping stuff (as they may be in some other languages). So the extra parentheses cause an extra attempt to evaluate the result, which is a Boolean, i.e. not a procedure, so this is an error.

Then, `'#f` is just `#f`; similarly for `#t` (they both evaluate to themselves); and a condition <s>`(= test #t)`</s><sup>1</sup> `(equal? test #t)` is the same as just `test` (produces the same set of Boolean results): *<sub>( <sup>1</sup> we can't use `=` to compare Booleans, it is supposed to be used with numbers only)</sub>*

```
(define (odd? x)
        (cond 
          ((= x 0) #f)
          ((= x 1) #t)
          ((even? (- x 1)) #f)
          (else #t)))
```

Also, `(if test #f else...)` is the same as `(if (not test) else... #f)`:

```
(define (odd? x)
        (cond 
          ((= x 0) #f)
          ((= x 1) #t)
          ((not (even? (- x 1))) #t)
          (else #f)))                 ; (else ...) is like (#t ...)
```

using logical connectives, the clauses with the same outcome can be merged, and mutually exclusive clauses can be rearranged (mutual exclusivity can be achieved with explicit guards):

```
(define (odd? x)
        (cond 
          ((and (/= x 0)              ; a guard
                (or (= x 1) 
                    (not (even? (- x 1))))) #t)
          ((or (= x 0) #t) #f)))
```

but `(cond (test #t) (else #f)` is `(if test #t #f)` which is just `test`:

```
(define (odd? x) (and (> x 0)         ; `>` is better
                      (or (= x 1) 
                          (not (even? (- x 1))))))
```

The guard `(> x 0)` prevents the fall-through for negative `x`es.

But then, this is *completely wrong*. For `n` to be odd, `n-1` *must* be even, not the opposite!

```
(define (odd? x) (and (> x 0)         ; work only for positive integers
                      (or (= x 1) 
                          (even? (- x 1)))))
```

We could write `(not (odd? (- x 1)))`, but then it wouldn't be tail recursive. It *would* be [tail recursive *modulo cons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Tail_recursion_modulo_cons) (*`not`* serving as a "constructor"), but for some historic fluke of a reason<sup>2</sup>, TRMC optimization isn't required of a Scheme implementation. *<sub>( <sup>2</sup> despite being [described **as early as 1974**.](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/cgi-bin/techreports/TRNNN.cgi?trnum=TR19))</sub>*

The last expression in `and` and `or` forms is, in fact, [in tail position](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-6.html#%_sec_3.5). But not in `not`.

Next, repeat the same for your definition of `even?`.

*See also:* [tailrecursion-modulo-cons](/questions/tagged/tailrecursion-modulo-cons).