# Need help understanding lists in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme

I'm having trouble understanding how Scheme forms and then detects lists.  Hows does it determine the difference between a list and a dotted pair?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16379759/1281433) to [Recursive range in Lisp adds a period?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16379657/1281433) includes an explanation of how pairs are used to implement lists in Scheme (and other Lisps).  It's not really clear what you're asking here, though.  A list is either the empty list `()`, or a pair whose `car` is the first element of the list and whose `cdr` is the rest of the list (another list).

Comment: what about your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886294/issues-with-conditionals-in-scheme)? Have you finished with it? If so, you can accept one of the answers to signal this to the other participants on this site. :)

Answer (score 2):

A list structure is formed from pairs. A proper list is a chain of pairs where the last pair has the empty list as its `cdr`.. We can make `list?` like this:

```
(define (list? lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) #t)
        ((pair? lst) (list? (cdr lst)))
        (else #f)))
```

Or you could use and/or:

```
(define (list? lst)
  (or (null? lst)
      (and (pair? lst)
           (list? (cdr lst)))))
```

Comment: It shouldn't.  A `cond` returning `#t` or `#f` is in indication that logical connectives are in order.